# Quasar: Use of Vue.js syntax (Vue instance and Vue.component)

Tags: vuejs2, quasar-framework

I am very new to Quasar.
I have started a project and so far felt comfortable with the structure.
Now I’d like to implement the following fiddle into my Index.vue file: https://jsfiddle.net/86216oko/

In all available Quasar tutorials, I have only seen the use of the “export default” and no sign of “new Vue” or “Vue.component”.

If I try to implement a new Vue instance, it spits the following error:

```
vue-router.esm.js?85f8:2128 ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
    at eval (Index.vue?b484:62)
    at Object../node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/webpack/loader.transform-quasar-imports.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/webpack/loader.auto-import-client.js?kebab!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/pages/Index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (0.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (Index.vue?f4bd:1)
    at Module../src/pages/Index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (0.js:68)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (Index.vue?2d70:1)
    at Module../src/pages/Index.vue (0.js:56)
```

What am I missing?
I guess there is probably a way to do set up multiple specific vue instances and vue.components for different divs through export default or somehow use the vue-normal syntax.

Pretty much the only thing I want to do is to use a vue component in Quasar: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

I also found an approach to do it with the “export default” (https://itnext.io/dynamic-component-creation-in-vue-js-b002bb41aaf4), but this whole thing is still a big question mark for me.

I’d appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also use quasar in my app, I implemented components the following way:

1. Create a new vue file with your component
2. Import your component in your parents file like described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration):

   import ComponentA from './ComponentA.vue'
   export default {
   components: { ComponentA }, //
   ... }
3. Use the component in the parents file like

   <\MyComponent>

[Here](https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/142/adding-a-vue-component/3) is a full example.

Comment: Thanks that helped.
In this quasar forum I present how it finally worked: https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/6497/use-of-vue-component-in-quasar/5?_=1596219616226

really helpful for me to understand basic concepts of integrating was also the following example of a todolist with quasar: https://codesandbox.io/s/o29j95wx9?file=/components/TodoList.vue